# Wire:click is not working in layout or include header files in livewire laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire

I have used wire:click function from header file. This header included in layout file. But it is not working. If i use in main template file, then it is working. Anybody knows why this is happened?

Header.blade.php,

```
<button wire:click="myFunction()">Notifications</button>
```

Comment: It must be within a Livewire component

Comment: @Qirel How can we add header file within the Livewire component